# How can I carry cookies in php to multiple subdomain

Tags: php, apache, cookies

I want to carry some cookies value to different subdomains like

`blog.mydomain.com , profile.mydomain.com , stats.mydomain.com, etc.`

Right now I am using below code to set cookies

`setcookie('var_name', 'var_value', null, "/", '.mydomain.com' );`

With this code, cookies set on `blog.mydomain.com` available on  `mydomain.com` but not on other subdomain (`profile.mydomain.com , stats.mydomain.com, etc.`)

Please, let me know, whats wrong with my code .

Comment: Your example code should work.

Comment: Yes, your solution should work, what's your problem?

Comment: To make my question more clear , I edited it. plz check it now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try:

```
$res = setcookie('var_name', 'var_value', null, "/", '.mydomain.com' );
var_dump($res); exit;
```

the output should be `TRUE`, if you see `false` it means output exists prior to calling this function and you can't set cookies after beginning sending content

Comment: thanks for your reply, its my mistake in testing. I deleted all cache , cookies, and restarted browser and it's working now. Sorry for taking your precious time

Answer (score 1):

You're doing the correct thing (as far as I know). Refer to the [PHP setcookie documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php).

***domain***

> The domain that the cookie is available. To make the cookie available on all subdomains of example.com then you'd set it to '.example.com'.

Do you have any problems retrieving the value on the other domains?

Comment: thanks for your reply, its my mistake in testing. I deleted all cache , cookies, and restarted browser and it's working now. Sorry for taking your precious time