# PHP isn't saving session when it's an ajax call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, session

**Hi all**,
i'm testing out a service for **internal ads** on our website...
I need to save **internal session** (PHP) to know what ads have been displayed and some other protection stuff...

The problem is that if i **access to the API throught webbrowser GET or POST** it **does session** (and saves the cookie of php session), but if i use `jQuery.ajax()` method it **doesn't save it**...

My link for tests is http://search.microdual.com
*(this is because i wanted a customized google search on my laptop :p)*

I suggest you to use **firebug** to take a look at the **javascript code**. (PHP code isn't needed because it is working on clicks...)
To simplify the debugging, i print out on **response json array from server** the session id on the var `{id_sessao:"..."}`...

Thanks in advance,
José Moreira

**EDIT:**

**Headers from server:**

```
Date    Wed, 08 Sep 2010 11:24:48 GMT
Server  Apache/2.2.8 (Ubuntu)
P3P CP="NOI NID ADMa OUR IND UNI COM NAV"
Cache-Control   private, must-revalidate
Access-Control-Allow-Orig...    *
Access-Control-Allow-Cred...    true
Access-Control-Allow-Meth...    OPTIONS, GET, POST
Access-Control-Allow-Head...    Content-Type, Depth, User-Agent, X-File-Size, X-Requested-With, If-Modified-Since, X-File-Name, Cache-Control
Set-Cookie  SN4b55935921bde=7ad280272050b4b44f17769909fd6f34; path=/ SN4b55935921bde=7ad280272050b4b44f17769909fd6f34; path=/
Keep-Alive  timeout=15, max=97
Connection  Keep-Alive
Transfer-Encoding   chunked
Content-Type    text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

**Headers from the jQuery Ajax request:**

```
Host    www.microdual.com
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; pt-PT; rv:1.9.2.8) Gecko/20100722 Firefox/3.6.8
Accept  application/json, text/javascript
Accept-Language pt-pt,pt;q=0.8,en;q=0.5,en-us;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding gzip,deflate
Accept-Charset  ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Keep-Alive  115
Connection  keep-alive
Content-Type    application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Referer http://search.microdual.com/
Content-Length  29
Origin  http://search.microdual.com
Pragma  no-cache
Cache-Control   no-cache
```

**Where is the cookie control on the jQuery Ajax Request?**

Comment: JS or PHP? http://ajax.microdual.com/js/jquery.microdualgetad-1.0.0.js

Comment: @CuSS is your Ajax request script actually continuing the session using `session_start()`?

Comment: @Pekka yes, try to click on a Ad Image and look at the headers throught firebug, it sends cookie. Ajax not.

Comment: @Cuss you don't happen to be setting the session cookie in a subdirectory of the domain?

Comment: PHP code and the code that you put HTML must be uncompressed

Comment: @Pekka can you explain better? i have only `session_start()` at the beginning of the file

Comment: @CuSS never mind, it's not in a sub directory (I didn't see the `path=/`)

Comment: @Pekka the problem is that if you go directly from browser to the url and see the headers, the browser sends the cookie, the ajax not. :(

Comment: @CuSS aah, I think I know what the problem is. Hang on, I'll write an answer

Comment: @andres_descalzo it's uncompressed now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is probably that your parent document is on `search.microdual.com`, and you are requesting a script from `www.microdual.com`. The session cookie isn't transported across domains.

If you are not using `document.domain` - I don't see it anywhere? - you will also have the additional problem that the AJAX call fails due to the [Single Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript).

To fix the cookie issue, you could either

- set the cookie's domain to `.microdual.com` so it works in both sub-domains
- carry the session across manually in the URL (`?sessionid=xxxxx`) and continue the session using `session_id("xxxxx");`.
- put both scripts on the same sub-domain (`search.microdual.com`)

The latter would be the easiest way.

Comment: How do i set the cookie to multiple domains? To work with `microdual.com`, `search.microdual.com` and `example.com` (like `*` ?) because i will put these ads on multiple pages from our company, but the php script will be always on `www.microdual.com`

Comment: @CuSS see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2392990/how-can-i-carry-cookies-in-php-to-multiple-subdomain

Comment: @CuSS probably yes, but as I said, you will then get cross domain problems as well

Comment: +1 for server not retaining session across domains.  terrible if you're just doing http and https on your own site.